# Input type=range does not update its value

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following:

```
 <input id="slider-min" type="range" min="0" max="55" value="0" 
 step="5" onchange="sliderMinUpdate(this.value)">,

<div id="min_input">0</div>

<input id="slider-day" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="0" 
 step="0.5" onchange="sliderDayUpdate(this.value)">

function sliderDayUpdate(value){
  $('#slider-min').val(0);
}

function sliderMinUpdate(value){
$('#min_input').text(value);    
}
```

When I focus in `slider-min` using keyboard and select keypad right or left it updates values in `min_input` correctly. When I change `slider-day` it fires `onChange` and updates the value from `slider-min` to 0 and I can see it working in my page (the slider returns to 0). The problem occurs when I select the first increment of `slider-min`, in this case 5. When the `onChange` from `slider-day` is called it updates `slider-min` to 0, correctly, but when I move from 0 to 5(`slider-min`) it does not work. If I continue moving it works.

Looks like the state 5 was maintained in `slider-min`, so when I set `$('#slider-min').val(0)`, the slider is updated, but when I change from 0 to 5, the `onchange="sliderMinUpdate(this.value)"` is not called.

Have no idea what's going on.

Comment: doris knows html5 . ask her :-)

Comment: With d3 use .property instead of .attr
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35632263/6305204

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little confused by your question, and this answer might be wrong, irrelevant, or too late, but I came across something potentially similar with Chrome v23 (current as of 24/12/12). As far as I know, jQuery uses getAttribute() and setAttribute() to interact with normal elements, but these functions do not seem to work for <input type="range">. Since there is no need for jQuery here (other than to simplify the selectors), I would recommend using the normal DOM document.getElementById('rangeElement').value = x; to get/set the value of the slider.

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

1. change the value and
2. trigger an `onchange` event.

I have been doing this with  jQuery + QUnit + FuncUnit to handle the waits, but  the following should only need jQuery.

```
$('input[type="range"]').val('0.5').trigger('change');
```

where `(min <= '0.5' => max)`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but not using jQuery but D3.js. As jimmetry already stated in his answer, jQuery seems not to be able to properly return the value
of an `<input type="range">`. The same seems to hold true for D3.js.

In my case this lines of code returned no updated values, but always their  *initial* value.

```
var min = $("#slider-min").attr("value");              // using jQuery
var min = d3.select("#slider-min").attr("value");      // using D3
```

Using the old-fashioned way, surprisingly the updated values were always returned:

```
var min = document.getElementById('slider-min').value;
```